# Swift: press button in external app via accessibility

Tags: swift, accessibility

In my function, I run the following code, when a specific event shows up and Safari is in foreground:

```
if win.safariIsForeground() {
    let el = AXUIElementCreateApplication(win.getSafariPid())
    var ptr: CFArray?
                
    _ = AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(el, &ptr)
}
```

The pointer returns an array that looks like this:

> ["AXFunctionRowTopLevelElements", "AXFrame", "AXChildren",
> "AXFocusedUIElement", "AXFrontmost", "AXRole", "AXExtrasMenuBar",
> "AXMainWindow", "AXFocusedWindow", "AXTitle",
> "AXChildrenInNavigationOrder", "AXEnhancedUserInterface",
> "AXRoleDescription", "AXHidden", "AXMenuBar", "AXWindows", "AXSize",
> "AXPosition"]

I'd like to make Safari go one site back in the history. I think I will need AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue and AXUIElementPerformAction to do that but how do I find out the button's attribute and how do I call check AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue for that?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do that is by accessing the menu item. Using `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue` works best with the provided constants:

```
// get menu bar
    var menuBarPtr: CFTypeRef?
    _ = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(safariElement, kAXMenuBarRole as CFString, &menuBarPtr)
    
    guard let menuBarElement = menuBarPtr as! AXUIElement? else {
        fatalError()
    }
```

Accessibility Inspector shows me, what items are child of the menu bar:
[image]

so lets get the children using `kAXChildrenAttribute`:

```
// get menu bar items
    var menuBarItemsPtr: CFTypeRef?
    _ = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(menuBarElement, kAXChildrenAttribute as CFString, &menuBarItemsPtr)
    
    guard let menuBarItemsElement = menuBarItemsPtr as AnyObject as! [AXUIElement]? else {
        fatalError()
    }
```

And so on all the way down to the menu item. Items also have an unique identifier that can look like `_NS:1008`. I'm not sure how to access them directly but by using `AXUIElementPerformAction` I can simply simulate pressing the menu item (action will be `kAXPressAction`).

I can use `kAXRoleAttribute` to identify the type of the item and where it occurs in the Accessibility hierarchy (see "Role:")
[image]

As I'm still a beginner at Swift, that was a quite challenging task as this is also not documented very well. Thanks a lot to Dexter who also helped me to understand this topic: [kAXErrorAttributeUnsupported when querying Books.app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66969764/macos-accessibility-api-kaxerrorattributeunsupported-when-querying-books-app)

Answer (score -1):

In your case you don't need necessarily need to use `AXUI` accessibility API. It's arguably simpler to send key strokes. You can go back in Safari history to previous page with `CMD[`. As an added bonus Safari does not need to be in foreground anymore.

```
let pid: pid_t = win.getSafariPid();
let leftBracket: UInt16 = 0x21
let src = CGEventSource(stateID: CGEventSourceStateID.hidSystemState)
let keyDownEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: leftBracket, keyDown: true)
keyDownEvent?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand
let keyUpEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: leftBracket, keyDown: false)
keyDownEvent?.postToPid(pid)
keyUpEvent?.postToPid(pid)
```

Your app running on Mojave and newer MacOS versions will need the `System Preferences` -> `Security & Privacy` -> `Accessibility` permisions granted to be eligible for sending keystrokes to other apps.

The keyboard codes can be looked up:
[here](https://gist.github.com/swillits/df648e87016772c7f7e5dbed2b345066) & [here visually](https://web.archive.org/web/20160509091827/http://x86osx.com/bbs/c_data/pds_comment/MacintoshToolboxEssentials.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already found a solution on my own and as it might not be perfect, it works pretty okay. I actually tried out your approach beforehand, however this only seems to work with a specific keyboard type (English?) but using a different type of keyboard didn’t seem to work in my tests (I’m using a German keyboard).